# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class [C ([B and [C are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Tags: java, json, jodd

I am trying to run my java project from cmd and taking back this error:

```
    **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class [C ([B and [C are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
            at jodd.util.UnsafeUtil.getChars(UnsafeUtil.java:67)
            at jodd.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:201)
            at IndexTester.main(IndexTester.java:78)**
```

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.util.Map;
    
    import jodd.json.JsonParser;
    
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.LeafReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.SlowCompositeReaderWrapper;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.Terms;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum;
    import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
    import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
    import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.simple.SimpleQueryParser;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
    
    
    public class IndexTester {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
            
            if (args.length != 3) {
                System.err.println("Incorrect number of arguments! Usage:");
                System.err.println("");
                System.err.println("java IndexTester should_clear_index path_to_data path_to_index ");
                System.err.println("\tif should_clear_index is \"1\", the index will be rebuilt. Otherwise, it will try and use an existing index.");
                System.err.println("\tpath_to_index should point to an empty directory somewhere.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            
            String shouldClearIndex = args[0];
            String inputPath = args[1]; // where to find the file containing the JSON to index
            String idxDirPath = args[2]; // where to put/find the Lucene index we want to search
            
            
            File inputFile = new File(inputPath);
            
            // set up analyzer:
            StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
            
            // set up the index
            File idxDir = new File(idxDirPath);
        
            Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(idxDir.toPath());
            
            if (shouldClearIndex.compareTo("1") == 0) {
                System.out.println("Rebuilding index...");
            
                IndexWriterConfig idxConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
                idxConfig.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE);
                IndexWriter idxWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, idxConfig);
    
                // Now, populate the index:
                int idx = 0;
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
                
                for (String line : Files.readAllLines(inputFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
                    // On large amounts of data, this can take a while
                    if (idx % 10000 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(idx);
                    }
                    idx++;
                    
                    // each line of the input file is a serialized JSON object
                    Map j = jParser.parse(line);
                    // simple types (strings, numbers, etc.) are handled like so:
                    String title = (String)j.get("title");
                    // complex types (lists or dicts) get turned into instances of
                    // java.util.Map and java.util.List.
                    String ab = (String)j.get("abstract");
    
                    // Look at the docs for TextField to see about other types- Lucene can index numbers, dates, etc.
                    Field tiField = new Field("title", title, TextField.TYPE_STORED); 
                    // The TYPE_STORED directive tells Lucene to actually store the original token in the index. This is handy 
                    // for all sorts of reasons!
                    
                    // set up any additional fields here
    
                    Document thisDoc = new Document();
                    thisDoc.add(tiField);
    
                    // add our document to the index
                    idxWriter.addDocument(thisDoc);
    
                }
    
                System.out.println("Done!");
    
                System.out.println(idx + " documents indexed.");
    
                idxWriter.close();
    
            }
    
            do {
                // Open up the index for querying:
                DirectoryReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
    
            
                // Tell me about the index (comment in/out as needed- this may be useful for debugging):
    //          LeafReader slowC = SlowCompositeReaderWrapper.wrap(reader); 
    //          Terms idxTerms = slowC.terms("title"); // change to a different field as needed
    //          TermsEnum tEnum = idxTerms.iterator(null);
    //          System.out.println("Terms in the index for the title field:");
    //          while (tEnum.next() != null) {
    //              String s = tEnum.term().utf8ToString();         
    //              System.out.println(s + "\t" + tEnum.docFreq());
    //          }
            
            
                // Now search
                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
            
                // Things to note re: QueryParser:
                // 1.   The first argument is the "default" field to search- 
                //      if nothing else is specified, in the query, this is what
                //      will be searched.
                // 2.   You always want to make sure to use the same Analyzer for your
                //      query as you did when you built the index!
                //
                // Other query parser classes will behave similarly, but may have different argument ordering.
            
                QueryParser qParser = new QueryParser("title", analyzer); 
            
            
                System.out.print("Query: ");
                String queryText = System.console().readLine();
            
                if (queryText.compareTo("") != 0) {
            
                    Query q = qParser.parse(queryText);
                    TopDocs results = searcher.search(q,  10);
                    System.out.println("Got " + results.totalHits + " hits!");
                    for (ScoreDoc d : results.scoreDocs) {
                        System.out.println(d.doc + "\t" + d.score);
                        Document res = reader.document(d.doc);
                        System.out.println(res.getField("title").stringValue());
                    }
                }
                
            } while (true); // keep querying until user hits ctrl-C
            
        }
    
    }
```

This is my code and thiis is my .txt file:
[https://openeclass.uom.gr/modules/document/file.php/DAI148/%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%BE%CE%B7%2006%20-%20%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%B2%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%BC%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7%20%CE%91%CE%BD%CE%AC%CE%BA%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%B7%2C%20%CE%9C%CE%BF%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BF%20%CE%94%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%BD%CF%85%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D%20%CE%A7%CF%8E%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%85/Using%20Lucene/data.txt.zip]

Comment: That's not enough information. You should show that `main` method and the json file that you are trying to parse (not in the comments, please [edit] the question and add the information).

Comment: i also use lucene libs

Comment: The problem, as the error shows you, is in the json parsing, it doesn't matter what you are trying to do after that. Now, please replace the link to the text file with a sample of the actual text file. If the lines are not all similar, find the line where this fails (use a debugger, check what the `idx` is).

Comment: i am trying to open my .txt file,that contains articles in JSON type, but it's crashing and not responding. Is that also a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please switch to the latest [Jodd JSON](https://json.jodd.org) v6.

There is probably an issue with the `UnsafeUtil.getChars`. What you can do is the following:

```
jParser.parse(line.toCharArray());
```

i.e. to skip using the `UnsafeUtil.getChars()`.

The new version of Jodd is not using the Unsafe class anymore.

Comment: I solve it.This was the problem, i updated to the latest jodd-all version! Thank you,